# Displaying C# code in Wordpress.com

Tags: c#, wordpress, widget, wordpress.com

I have researched this for a few hours and I am kind of frustrated. Maybe I am just missing something as I am new to blogging.

I am ***not*** hosting my own blog, I am just using WordPress.com.
I want to include snippets of c# code and have them look like they do in Visual Studio, or at least make them look nice, certainly with line numbers and color.
The solutions I have seen for this all seem to assume you are hosting your own blog.
I cannot figure out how to install plugins.

Is there a widget that will make code snippets look nice, or some other solution I can easily use?

Thank you

**EDIT**: Sarfraz has outlined one way to solve my problem (thank you!), and I have tried it but there is an issue I have, namely that it does not colorize most of my code (newer keywords like **var**, **from**, **where**, **select**, etc). Is there a fix to this or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just edit your aricles in **html** mode and enclose your code within these tags.

```
[sourcecode language="css"]
[/sourcecode]
```

Example:

```
[sourcecode language="javascript"]
 // javascript hello world program
 alert('Hello, World !!');
[/sourcecode]
```

**Note:** You need to specify correct language identifier for the `language` attribute as shown above.

**[More Information Here :)](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/)**

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that whitespace formatting is lost this way?

Comment: Nope, your code looks cleaner with required white space. thanks

Comment: If it is this simple, why do so many plugins exist, some of them complicated to install? Thanks for the link btw :)

Comment: @Stomp: the difference with plugins is that they automate it, not doing it manually, also plugins provide a variety of themes for the code, also you can not add code plugin to wordpress.com. Hope that helps. thanks bye.

Comment: @Stomp: I deleted my answer as I missed the fact that you're on wordpress.com, not self-hosted. You have to stay with the codemarkup as outlined by Sarfraz....

Comment: Where do you insert square brackets in HTML? Is there an example on how exactly to do it? Really confusing.

Answer (score 7):

The [sourcecode] tag usually works fine for C#, but for me it often breaks when I post XAML code.

Instead I use [this page](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/) to format my code. The result looks nice (you can see it on [my blog](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/)), but it requires the "Custom CSS" option ($15/year).

---

EDIT: actually the [sourcecode] tag works fine, and I'm now using it in all my posts

Answer (score 6):

```
    [code language="csharp"]
       //Your code here
    [/code]
```

Answer (score 4):

looks like this has been updated, now you can use

```
[code language="[the lang you are posting]"]
your code here
[/code]
```

note: you can shorthand language as lang

```
[code lang="[the lang you are posting]"]
your code here
[/code]
```

[here is the list of supported languages](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/)